# Is it possible to recover data from nvme hdd?

Tags: hdd

The NVME hdd from my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) stops working 1 or 2 minutes after booting freezing everything as soon as I open the finder.

If I try to boot into recovery mode it shows no disk on the disk selection step, as if the amount of time it can work is not enough to boot up.

I installed the OS on an external HDD and boot from it, for the first 1 minute or so I can see the internal hdd, but once I start to transfer data it stops working and disappear.
Doesn't show even with list disk

Is there a way to make it work for more time and transfer the data I want?
Like, is there some sort of workaround/
thanks

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the problem. Which MBP model, how does the "stop working" show?

Comment: Are you sure this is an SSD failure? Have you tried booting in safe mode (press the Shift key during boot)?

Comment: @Jean_JD during the safe mode booting the disk won’t show up.

Comment: If you can boot in Safe mode, the disk is present. What is the result of terminal command `diskutil list `?

Comment: I would suggest the next step is to use the SSD in an external enclosure to determine wether the issue is the SSD itself and not another hardware issues with your MacBook.